# Confused about the big O notation of the code

Tags: python, big-o

I was trying to find if the given strings are anagrams without using any helper sort function and nested loops.

Therefore I tried using a while loop; however, I am not sure what the big O notation of this code is. Can you please help?

```
def anagrams(string1, string2):
    if len(string1) != len(string2):
        return False
    string3 = ""
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while x < len(string1) and y < len(string2):
        element = string1[x]
        if element == string2[y]:
            string3 += element
            x += 1
            y = 0
        else:
            y += 1
    return string1 == string3
```

Comment: This code tests are string1 and string2 anagrams? Does it work?

Comment: Are you interested in the time complexity, the space complexity or a combination of both? Big-O notation can be used for either.

Comment: does it check whether `sorted(string1) == sorted(string2)` (`O(n log n)` time) i.e., `len(string1) == len(string2) and all(string1.count(c) == string2.count(c) for c in set(string1))` (`O(n)` time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it will be O(n^2) because your x value tends to increment, but your y value can continue to be reset to zero, therefore being no better than a nested loop.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I find if two strings are anagrams so that it is better than O(n^2) or nested loops?

Comment: sort both strings as character arrays and compare.  The sort should be O(n logn)

Comment: Trying to avoid sorting. That was helpful though. Thank you!

Comment: you can make two int arrays n elements long where n is the number of possible characters (256 for ascii). Initialize each array with zeros. Loop through each string and increment the array index of the char value for each. Now each array has the number of each character present in one or the other strings, simply loop through the array and compare. This assumes you are using a small character set.  The runtime would be O(n).

Comment: _That seems good. I just did something similar but using dictionary. Is it Okay?_

def anagrams(string1, string2):
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    for letter in string1:
        dict1[letter] = 0
    for letter in string2:
        dict2[letter] = 0
    for letter in string1:
        dict1[letter] += 1
    for letter in string2:
        dict2[letter] += 1
    return dict1 == dict2

print anagrams('barug', 'arugb')

Comment: A dictionary would work, the arrays would be faster, but the dictionary could take less space. Either way the runtime is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide an explicit example.
First of all,Let's say string1 = 'ABC' and string2 = 'DE'.
len(string1) = 3, len(string2) = 2
We first compare string1[0] and string2[0], not the same, y++;
We second compare string1[0] and string2[1], not the same, y++;
Get out of the loop; returns false
Second, Let's say string1 = 'ABC' and string2 = 'AC'
We first compare string1[0] and string2[0], the same, x++; string3 += string1[0]
We second compare string1[1] and string2[1], not the same, y++;
Get out of the loop, returns false

Third, Let's say string1 = 'AB' and string2 = 'AB'
We first compare string1[0] and string2[0], the same, x++; string3 += string1[0]
string3 = 'A'
We second compare string1[1] and string2[0], not the same, y++;
We third compare string1[1] and string2[1], the same, x++; string3 += string1[1] string3 = 'AB'
; we know it is going to return true

Therefore, O(n+m), given n = len(string1), m = len(string2). Thanks

Comment: ***If two strings have different lengths, it will return false without proceeding further. Any way thank you! ***

Comment: Just for clarification: to be precise, big Oh notation only includes the highest element of a polynomial, so a run time of a simple function of (m+n) is O(n) or O(m), O(m+n) is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The code is O(N^2) in runtime, but isn't correct.

The code is equivalent to:

```
def anagrams(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2): return False
    r = ''
    for s in s1:
        if s in s2: r += s
    return r == s1
```

Written this way, it's obvious that it's O(N^2).

This checks that each character in s1 is also in s2, but that's not sufficient to detect anagrams: you must also check the counts for each character are correct.

Here's a counter-example to the correctness of the algorithm: "abba" and "barf".

Comment: *I think it checks the counts for each character. Anyway thank you!*

Comment: @user4592697 You think your code is correct or you checked it returns the correct result on the counter-example I gave you?

Comment: _Oops! I am sorry! You are right :)
Can you suggest on how to reduce the time complexity?_

Comment: @user4592697 you can search for existing answers on this site.